# God resque start gives "The server is not available"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment, resque, god

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get God to restart resque.

I've got a Rails 3.2.2 stack on a Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS Linode slice. Its running system Ruby 1.9.3-p194 (no RVM).

There's a God init.d service at `/etc/init.d/god-service` that contains:

```
CONF_DIR=/etc/god
GOD_BIN=/var/www/myapp.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/god
RUBY_BIN=/usr/local/bin/ruby
RETVAL=0

# Go no further if config directory is missing.
[ -d "$CONF_DIR" ] || exit 0

case "$1" in
    start)
        # Create pid directory
        $RUBY_BIN $GOD_BIN -c $CONF_DIR/master.conf
        RETVAL=$?
  ;;
    stop)
        $RUBY_BIN $GOD_BIN terminate
        RETVAL=$?
  ;;
    restart)
        $RUBY_BIN $GOD_BIN terminate
        $RUBY_BIN $GOD_BIN -c $CONF_DIR/master.conf
        RETVAL=$?
  ;;
    status)
        $RUBY_BIN $GOD_BIN status
        RETVAL=$?
  ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: god {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

`master.conf` in the above contains:

```
load "/var/www/myapp.com/current/config/resque.god"
```

`resque.god` in the above contains:

```
APP_ROOT  = "/var/www/myapp.com/current"
God.log_file  = "/var/www/myapp.com/shared/log/god.log"


God.watch do |w|
  w.name = 'resque'
  w.interval = 30.seconds
  w.dir = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..'))
  w.start = "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=*"
  w.uid = "deploy"
  w.gid = "deploy"

  w.start_grace = 10.seconds
  w.log = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..','log','resque-worker.log'))

  # restart if memory gets too high
  w.transition(:up, :restart) do |on|
    on.condition(:memory_usage) do |c|
      c.above = 200.megabytes
      c.times = 2
    end
  end

  # determine the state on startup
  w.transition(:init, { true => :up, false => :start }) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
      c.running = true
    end
  end

  # determine when process has finished starting
  w.transition([:start, :restart], :up) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
      c.running = true
      c.interval = 5.seconds
    end

    # failsafe
    on.condition(:tries) do |c|
      c.times = 5
      c.transition = :start
      c.interval = 5.seconds
    end
  end

  # start if process is not running
  w.transition(:up, :start) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
      c.running = false
    end
  end
end
```

In `deploy.rb` I have a reload task:

```
task :reload_god_config do
  run "god stop resque"
  run "god load #{File.join(deploy_to, 'current', 'config', 'resque.god')}"
  run "god start resque"
end
```

The problem is whether I deploy, or run `god (stop|start|restart|status) resque` manually, I get the error message:

```
The server is not available (or you do not have permissions to access it)
```

I tried installing `god` to system gems and pointing to it in `god-service`:

```
GOD_BIN=/usr/local/bin/god
```

but `god start rescue` gives the same error.

However, I can start the service by doing:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/god-service start
```

So its probably a permissions issue, I think, probably related to the fact that the init.d service is owned by `root` and god is run from the bundle by the `deploy` user.

What's the best way around this issue?

Comment: i'm having the same problem. were you able to resolve it?

Comment: I'm just running my services without God, unfortunately, at the moment. When I get a chance I'm going to look at Bluepill.

Comment: Same issue anyone found a solution?

Comment: Ok this is an issue with your config files, check them all of them + the includes somewhere it fails throwing you this error.

Answer (score 0):

You're running the god service as a different user (there's a good chance root).

Also check out: [God not running: The server is not available (or you do not have permissions to access it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063623/god-not-running-the-server-is-not-available-or-you-do-not-have-permissions-to/29013627#29013627)

Answer (score 0):

First you check whether you have installed god in your machine using "god --version" command. If its available just try to run some god script with -D option. Example "god -c sample.god -D" it will give you some type of error messages in the standard output in your console where is the exact issue. I was also getting same error when i try to run the commmand without "-D" option. Then when i tried with "-D" mode it was told some folder write permission issue i could able to find it and fix it.

Answer (score -3):

Ok this is an issue with your config files, check them all of them + the includes somewhere it fails throwing you this error. I checked mine and fixes some errors afterwards it worked perfectly!

Comment: @Rubytastic Can you elaborate your answer??

Comment: Just check syntax there must be error in the syntax of config file, that was what i ment. In my case this resolved the issue. Since switched from god.